# I am not able to add the url of my community page to chat with customers section in service console

Tags: community, liveagent, einstein, chat, cors

I am trying to implement chatbot on my community page so when i am trying to add the url into service console's chat with customer section, but it says "Origins may not contain paths or queries, since they are not part of the origin".

My Url is something like this
https://xyz-pqrs.force.com/abc  (Dummy URL)

I tried with firefox as well but it didn't work. When I go with "https://xyz-pqrs.force.com", it works but i need to go with my exact URL.
I have already whitelisted "https://*.force.com" in the CORS.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove everything past the ".com" so copy in " https://xyz-pqrs.force.com"